# SQL INNER JOIN DISTINCT RESULT

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables SelfAnswers and Employee . When doing the following query:I want to return distinct result .

```
SELECT  s.Id,s.EmployeeId,e.NAME,e. Department
            FROM SelfAnswers AS s Inner Join Employee As e ON s.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
```

Output is

```
Id   EmployeeId    NAME    Department  
1    100           adam     Exam
2    100           adam     Exam
3    100           adam     Exam
4    100           adam     Exam   
5    101           smith    Exam
6    101           smith    Exam
7    101           smith    Exam
8    101           smith    Exam
```

Comment: USE DISTINCT ON SELECT STATEMNT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the query is returning distinct results.

If you were refering to `EmployeeId, NAME and Department`, then you could try something like

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        s.EmployeeId,
        e.NAME,
        e. Department
FROM    SelfAnswers AS s Inner Join 
        Employee As e   ON  s.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
```